# EF inserts a DB generated key, ignoring DatabaseGeneratedOption.None

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, primary-key, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using EF 6.1.3 Code First.

I have 2 classes:

- Employee
- Decision

Employees are loaded from a file, that includes a unique `EmployeeID` for each.

My application lets the user enter and save new Decisions regarding these Employees.
However, when EF saves the new Decision to the DBContext, **EF overwrites the Employee's EmployeeID with a DB generated value**.

So, I added the attribute `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` as follows, to Employee.EmployeeID:

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

Next, I deleted the DB, deleted all migrations, and **added a new migration**.

However, this migration sets `identity` ("Value indicating whether or not the DB will generate values for this column during insert") to `true`:

```
CreateTable(
                "dbo.Employees",
                c => new
                    {
                        EmployeeID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
```

...so, that didn't help.

**Editing this Migration manually** (i.e., setting `identity` to `false`) causes an error to be thrown when trying to save the context:
`InnerException = {"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'EmployeeID', table '[...]DBContext.dbo.Employees'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated."}`

...although the EmployeeID in the context's Local DBSet is correct (not null, not generated).

I've been looking high and low for a solution, but all I can think of is a **sub-optimal work-around**: adding another, non-key property to Employee.

**Other things I've tried**, to no avail:

- using automatic migrations
- adding [ForeignKey("EmployeeID")] to Decision.Employee

---

**EDIT**:
As requested by E-Bat, here are excerpts from my entities:

```
public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    private int _employeeID;
    public int EmployeeID
    {
        get { return _employeeID; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _employeeID)
            {
                _employeeID = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(EmployeeID)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[and so on]

```
   public class Decision : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _decisionID;
        public int DecisionID
        {
            get { return _decisionID; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _decisionID)
                {
                    _decisionID = value;

                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(DecisionID)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private Employee _employee;
        public Employee Employee
        {
            get { return _employee; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _employee)
                {
                    _employee = value;

                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Employee)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[and so on]

Comment: Post the relevant code for those entity as well as the mapping setup

Comment: +1 not for the question, but for the level of detail in your question. This was very well written and easy to understand by the SO community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually applied the mapping attribute to the backing variable *_employeeID*, you need to get it applied to the property instead:

```
public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _employeeID;
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int EmployeeID
    {
        get { return _employeeID; }
        set
        {
         //Code omitted  
        }
    }
```